# Analytical solution for one specific root of a 6-degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Is there an analytic solution to this polynomial, for any $e\in [0, 6]$?

$p + p^2 + p^3 + p^4 + p^5 + p^6 = 6 - e$

I am only looking for the root which represents a probability, i.e. $p \in [0,1]$. **Is there an analytical expression that would express this $p$ root as a function of $e$?**

The only idea I had was to multiply by $(1 - p)$ which leads to:

$-p^7 + p(7 - e) = 6 - e$

which is equivalent to

$p(7 - e - p^6) = 6 - e$

but I am not sure how to solve these either.

Comment: A numerical value of $p$ we have found $p\approx 0.829625593832065$

Comment: For $e=\pm7,14$ is possible. Galois group in pari/gp: `polgalois(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6-6+e)`.

Comment: The case $e=7$ it is trivial according to your computation: $p^7=1$ and $0\le p\le 1$ gives $p=1$. What should $e$ be? A complex parameter, or an integer, or may be $e=\exp(1)$ after all?

Comment: Thank you guys, I am not looking for solution for specific $e$, but I wanna have the analytical expression for an arbitrary $e$ between 0 and 6. Please see the update.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov thanks for the tip! The `pari/gp` polgalois function gives analytical or numerical solution?

Comment: @Tomas not solution, only info about possible solubility of equation in "closed" form.

Answer (score 1):

Your Eq. is
$$(p)=p^6+p^5+p^4+p^3+p^2+p-(6-\epsilon)=0.$$
Let $0<\epsilon <6$. Then as per Descate's rule number of sign changes is just one in $f(p)$,
so it will have at most one real positive root. Further, $f(0)=\epsilon-6<0$ and $f(1)=\epsilon>0$, so by IVT this equation will have at least one real root in $(0,1)$. Hence this equation will have exactly one real root in $(0,1)$, which may be found numerically.

Comment: Thank you Zafar. I know there is a numerical solution; I am looking for analytic if possible. Thanks.